# How can I find matching values from a data frame and a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

[image]

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ano':[17]*5,
                   'Mes':[1]*5,
                   'Dia':[1]*5,
                   'Hora':[0,1,2,3,4],
                  'Rn':[2766400,3053333,3211333,3303166,3486833]})
```

And a string such that

```
ymdt=[17, 1, 1, 0]
```

which is year month day and time. (the string and the df are all int)

And what I need is find the ymdt value in the data frame and get the Rn value of that row in this case is the value 2766400. So far I have no clue how to do that with pandas, all I have found yet is regarding finding one value, but nothing to check full rows

Comment: I cannot understand/you did not include "the dataframe you are working with", so here's the general rule. If you want to filter a dataframe by column value being in a list, data_df_in = data_df[data_df.col_name.isin(some_list)]["col_we_want"] .  You can remove the last "col_we_want" if you rather filter the whole dataframe out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
df.loc[df[['Ano', 'Mes', 'Dia', 'Hora']].eq(ymdt).all(1), 'Rn']
```

Using dataframe column filtering and boolean indexing with pd.DataFrame.loc

Output:

```
0    2766400
Name: Rn, dtype: int64
```